# Operator induced by continuous function and measures

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

If $X$ is a compact metric space, and $T:X \rightarrow X$ is continuous map, what would be meant by $T_\ast$ is the operator on measures induced by $T$? Allow $\mu$ to be some Borel regular normed measure with some $\mathcal{A}$ a Borel partition of $X$. I have an idea that it means:

\begin{gather}
(T_\ast \mu )(A) = \mu(T^{-1} (A)).
\end{gather}

Just struggling to understand this definition. Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Also, I only tagged the areas that are related to the field I'm reading this paper in. I'm unsure what the heck it should be tagged as; thanks to any changes that occur here as well if you see a better tag it should be under.

Comment: Your idea is right. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure

Comment: So here is the rest of why I'm having trouble understanding it. Let $\sigma_n$ be a measure. Then define $\mu_n = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum^{n-1}_{k=0} T^k_\ast (\sigma_n)$. Not quite sure what this definition means, but assuming I am ok with it somehow, we proceed as follows. For any $f$ a real valued function on $X$, we show that $|(T_\ast \mu_n)(f) - \mu_n(f)| = \dfrac{1}{n} |(T^n_\ast \sigma_n)(f) - \sigma_n(f)|$. Also, $\sigma_n$ is a concentrated measure. Given some set $E_n$, $\sigma_n (\{x\}) = \dfrac{1}{|E_n|}$ for $x \in E_n$, and where $|E_n|$ means cardinality of $E_n$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand how and where $f$ moves in using what I thought was the correct interpretation. Because it's real-valued, I'm unsure of the juxtaposition after applying $T_\ast$.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, just to clarify everything, I should have taken some functional analysis at some point. Luiz, thank you, your answer was correct and that was the main question I asked. $T_\ast \mu = \mu(T^{-1})$, and this is commonly called the push through measure. I had completely forgot about this notation since taking some measure theory. But to answer the other part, if one ever sees $\mu(f)$ notation, this simply means Lebesgue integration; i.e. $\mu(f) = \int f \, d \mu$. This is quite common in every functional analysis text I've picked up since when I posted this. Thanks for the help from everyone as usual.